# Minizinc: Relax constraints when inconsistency found

Tags: minizinc

When getting in MiniZinc the message:

> WARNING: model inconsistency detected

That means that the Model is UNSATISFIABLE due to a specific constraint in some line of the Model, is there a way apart from commenting out the constraint that leads to the inconsistency to "relax" this constraint and Minizinc recalculates a solution?

Comment: In the newest MiniZinc version (v2.2.0) there is a solver - "findMUS" - that is for these kind of problems where it tries to identify the culprit.

Comment: thank you for the answer!
Using the command "--filter-named-exclude <name>" within the findMus compiler the number of MUS is reduced so this can be considered as a relax constraint technique practically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I copied my comment to a "formal" answer, so now you can accept the answer.)

In the newest MiniZinc version (v2.2.0) there is a solver - "findMUS" - that is for these kind of problems where it tries to identify the culprit.

Comment: from my understanding though using the solver FindMUS, it seems as it should be used only when the UNSATISIAFIBILITY is detected from another solver for example I use Gecode so a switch from the one solver to the other is required. FindMus cannot handle satisifiable problems right?

Comment: What I have understand, it's only  applicable for unsat models.